# Cross browser testing and assuming its support

Tags: browsers, compatibility-testing

Given I have tested my browser in latest chrome, how can I assume the from which version of browser my website is supported with?

**For example** Given I tested website in chrome 69 latest, is there any reference document that I can refer if Chrome 20 is supported.
I would like to view the same reference for the different type of Desktop/Mobile and Tablet browsers. I tried to check references in google but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 approaches to your problem that I know of.

1. Tell people official support is from 69 and up. Others might work but are not tested officially. In case of a bug, you will try fixing it.
2. The second method is going through stuff that you use and looking at W3Schools and your other technical documentation and extrapolating the supported version from it. Usually, frameworks have a page or two about supported version etc.
3. A bit of an ad-hoc approach could be downgrading your browser, running automated tests and if they fail, raise version and try again.

Most widely seen is number 1, if you have automated tests I recommend number 3.